# Accessing childnodes after first child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to access all html contents after first  tag element. Can any body please tell me how i can access it through jquery or javascript

```
<div id="mydiv" > 
<h4> h4 node </h4>
<p><b>bold</b></p>
<h1><b>bold</b></h1>
<b>bold</b>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:gt(0)` selector refers to *after the first element*:

```
var els = $("#mydiv > :gt(0)");
```

If you need all nodes after the first (including text nodes) use:

```
var els = $("#mydiv").contents().slice(1);
```

Comment: it is not giving the text nodes

Comment: @Dudling So you need to get all nodes including text nodes? You haven't that in the question.

Comment: yes , I need all nodes including text nodes

Comment: @Dudling Check the updated answer. There is another option.

Comment: var els = $("#mydiv").contents().slice(1);
only access <h4>, not all nodes and their text nodes

Comment: @Dudling Nope. `slice(1)` returns all nodes from the second and after. Read here: http://api.jquery.com/slice/.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to find all element within certain element first you have to find that element. This can be done in javascript with code `var x=document.getElementById("mydiv").children;`
Atfer that you can access its children like using array. For example x[0] will be first element inside mydiv, x[1] second, and so long...
Here is a sample code that prints innerHTML of second children of mydiv 
`<script>
var x=document.getElementById("mydiv").children;
document.write(x[1].innerHTML);
</script>`